# I want to build a function that converts a formula string in excel from absolute to relative references

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy

Using python I want to build a function that converts a formula string in excel from absolute to relative references.

For example; suppose the formula “=SUM(A1:A15)” is in cell A16 in excel, I would like the function to take in the formula string and the location where the formula is written (in this case cell A16) and output the formula in the R1C1 reference style, so it would give the string"=SUM(R[-15]C:R[-1]C)"

I have made the following progress:

I have read the excel formula into a numpy array, and converted them all into strings

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = r"C:\Form1.xlsx")
sheet_ranges = wb["Sheet1"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
    df1 = df1.astype(str)
    excelsheetdata_asNPA1= df1.to_numpy()
```

Using openpyxl.formula I have imported Tokenizer and defined a function, that takes the excel formula string and breaks the formula string into its constituent tokens.

```
from openpyxl.formula import Tokenizer   
def tok2 (c):
    this = Tokenizer(c)
    return this.items
```

I have run the function across the numpy array containing the excel formula and produced a numpy array of lists (array2) with each list containing the items from the Tokeniser function namely: a value, a type and a subtype.

```
String_Of_Formula = np.vectorize(tok2)
array2 = String_Of_Formula (excelsheetdata_asNPA1)
```

I now think the next step is to produce another array which is the same shape as 'array2' and which contains the same data except where the subtype = RANGE.

The formula “=SUM(A1:A15)” which is in cell A16 in excel means that array2 at position (15,0) reads "[FUNC OPEN SUM(:, OPERAND RANGE A1:A17:, FUNC CLOSE ):]", I think this is a list, but I'm not sure.

My difficulty is accessing the part of that list based on its contents. So I want to select the part of the list which has the word 'RANGE' in it, which in this case would return "OPERAND RANGE A1:A17" I then plan to edit this so that A1 becomes R[-15]C and A17 becomes R[-1]C. To make this edit I would also need to use the position, or index?? (15,0).

I think that array2 contains lists and as mentioned above array2 (15,0) returns "[FUNC OPEN SUM(:, OPERAND RANGE A1:A17:, FUNC CLOSE ):]"

```
pull = [FUNC OPEN SUM(:, OPERAND RANGE A1:A17:, FUNC CLOSE ):]

pull [1]
Out[219]: OPERAND RANGE A1:A17:

pul2 = pull [1]

pul2 [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-221-e68f9727e90f>", line 1, in <module>
    pul2 [1]

TypeError: 'Token' object is not subscriptable
```

The lowest level within my array2 is a [Token] and I need help as to how to search on the contents of a token and edit the token before putting it into a new array.

Any help would be most welcome, thank you.

Comment: _I get: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'_ What do you understand from that error message? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: good comment, thank you, I hope the edit has clarified?

Answer (score 0):

The Token has three attributes:

- `value`: The string value parsed that led to this token
- `type`: A string identifying the type of token
- `subtype`: A string identifying subtype of the token (optional, and
  defaults to "")

Which can be accessed simply by putting .value .type or .subtype after the [index] as follows:
pull[1].subtype
gives the output
RANGE

and
pull[1].value
gives the output
'A1:A15'